# In java is there a way to tell on which physical computer a file resides?

Tags: java, file-io

I have an eclipse RCP product that is run by multiple people at our company.  All PCs are running some version of Windows.  We have access to a shared PC which different people have mapped to different drive letters.  That means the same file may be referred to in many different ways depending on the PC on which program is run.  E.g.

- \communalPC\Shared\foo.txt
- Y:\Shared\foo.txt
- Z:\Shared\foo.txt

I want to programmatically check if an arbitrary file is on the communnal PC.  Is there a robust way to do this in java?

Our current solution below is a bit of a hack  It is not robust due to people mapping to different drive letters, changing drive letters, not-portable etc.

```
private static boolean isOnCommunalPc(File file) {
    if(file.getAbsolutePath().toLowerCase().startsWith("\\\\communalPC")) {
        return true;
    }

    if(file.getAbsolutePath().toLowerCase().startsWith("y:")){
        return true;
    }

    if(file.getAbsolutePath().toLowerCase().startsWith("z:")){
       return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: From your code sample it looks like the file is always on the communal PC?

Comment: Thanks, that was a typo.  I changed the last return statement from true to false.

Comment: It is a good start to get the absolute path.  On Windows that can be combined with a running an external script to determine the mapping paths of drives. In cmd.exe, the "net use" command prints the mapping of all network drive paths at the network level. If the drive you get from the absolute path is not in the "net use" list then it must be on localhost and should be the same as that given by runnning "echo %cd%" from an external script in Windows.

Comment: Using "net use" is a great idea for our situation as we only run on Windows and it gets around hard coding drive letters.  I think that has solved my most immediate pressing problem.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java cannot tell the difference of which machine the file is on, as Windows abstracts that layer away from the JVM. You can, however be explicit with your connection.

Is there a reason why you couldn't have an ftp or http server (or even a custom java server!) on the communal pc, and to access it via a hostname or an ip? That way, it doesn't matter where the user has mapped the network drive, you connected via a static address.

Accessing a remote file in Java is as easy as:

```
URL remoteUrl = new URL(String.format("%s/%s", hostName, fileName));
InputStream remoteInputStream remoteUrl.openConnection().getInputStream();
//copyStreamToFile(remoteInputStream, new File(destinationPath), false);
```

If you need the file to be local for a library or code you would prefer not to change, you could:

```
void copyStreamToFile(InputStream in, File outputFile, boolean doDeleteOnExit) {
    //Clean up file after VM exit, if needed.
    if(doDeleteOnExit)
        outputFile.deleteOnExit();
    FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
    ReadableByteChannel inputChannel = Channels.newChannel(in);
    WritableByteChannel outputChannel = Channels.newChannel(outputStream);
    ChannelTools.fastChannelCopy(inputChannel, outputChannel);
    inputChannel.close();
    outputChannel.close()
}
```

**EDIT** Accessing a remote file via Samba with [JCIFS](https://jcifs.samba.org/) is as easy as:

```
domain = ""; //Your domain, only set if needed.
NtlmPasswordAuthentication npa = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication(domain, userName, password);
SmbFile remoteFile =  new SmbFile(String.format("smb://%s/%s", hostName, fileName), npa);
//copyStreamToFile(new SmbFileInputStream(remoteFile), new File(destinationPath), false)
```

This will probably be the most pragmatic solution, as it requires the least amount of work on the Windows server. This plugs into the existing server framework in Windows, instead of installing more.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I agree that a better long term solution would be to mediate access to the communal pc via a server of some kind.  Unfortunately, that may take a bit of organizational change which can be a bit harder than coding! In the meantime, I'll take the answer as "No" it can't be done as the physical PC on which a file resides is abstracted away from the JVM.

Comment: @ranga, if you haven't already set up a server of another sort, check out my edit showing basic Samba usage.

Comment: Our problem is more that the user specifies files (from a gui or script) which may then be altered/deleted.  I'm looking for a way to safeguard against the accidental selection of communal files.  Come to think of it, we are looking for a way to prevent the process running on remote files, rather than connecting to remote files!  The permissions on the files should prevent this, but it is better to have multiple layers of defence in place.  The basic Samba usage you showed might be useful in a different context though. Thanks!